# What would cause glass to replace calcium carbonate in shells?

Tags: science-based, evolution, xenobiology, fauna, ocean

Sea creatures have some very pretty shells. Unfortunately, these shells are quite opaque, and much more boring to look at than they could be.

So what if they were made of glass. It’s not unheard of, glass sponges do it already. Unfortunately there are reasons as to why calcium carbonate is the chosen shell material, such as it’s greater durability.

So I want an explanation as to why aquatic creatures would pass on calcium carbonate and go for glass instead. The scenario can be adjusted from the starting point of earth however much is required, but of course less changes are better.

Comment: Glass sponges aren't made of glass, any more than a Koala bear is a bear.

Comment: @Richard glass sponges have siliceous spicules, which means they are made of silicon dioxide, which is the main component of glass, and the only component of quartz glass.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calcium carbonate is dissolved by acidic waters, while glass is more resistant. There is little point in evolving a shell which is dissolved in the very water you live in.

Therefore acidic waters might push the evolution of shell based on silicon dioxide.

Answer (score 3):

You could alternatively make the most abundant ocean sediment silicon dioxide instead of calcium carbonate. If only a slight change to a higher concentration of silicon dioxide and an increased acidity occur, which would happen naturally in a more acidic environment, then the evolutionary result could be glass shells. This kind of evolution might also lead to more organisms having the coloration of their environment as they won't have colored shells to use as camouflage.

An interesting side thought that I have not researched is that the decreased opaqueness would lead the organism to a more sheltered/shadowy lifestyle as the increased sun exposure could damage/harm the organism.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because the planet froze over, meaning that there was no light, or there was an event that pushed these sea creatures deeper into the ocean, where there is no light. Then, maybe the creatures have to generate their own bioluminescence to see, or for activities such as finding a partner. Another reason could be that glass is harder than calcite (in the Mohs scale at least), which could resist the pressure of the deep waters better.

Comment: Interesting thought however food would immediately become a limiting factor and bioluminescence would attract unwanted, predatory attention

Comment: Mohs is a measure of resistance to scratching.  If you're trying to resist pressure, you want a material with a high compressive strength instead.